# Typescript extending class to define property className

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` `Button` in my application, and I want to declare the class `ButtonPageChange` class that extends `Button` to define the value `'btn-loading'` in the property `className`.

Without using typescript I have the following `React` component:

```
export const ButtonPageChange = ({onClick, href, disabled, variant, size, className, children}) => {

    return (
        <Button onClick={onClick}
                href={href}
                disabled={disabled}
                variant={variant}
                size={size}
                className={'btn-loading ' + className ? className : ''}
                data-senna-off="true"
        >
            {children}
        </Button>
    )

};
```

How you can see i have to pass all the `props` to the `Button` component. I wanted to use Typescript to make this `ButtonPageChange` more clean. This is not a syntactically correct code but to give you an idea:

```
declare class ButtonPageChange extends Button {
    className: {'btn-loading ' + props.className},
    data-senna-off: "true"
}
```

I am starting with Typescript and I don't have any idea how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow your idea, however the problem here is shared between TS and JS, even if in TS you can use typed props to make this easier to follow along.

[React is based on composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), so you can't really `extend` a component (inheritance). Even if you can do it, you can use a composition solution:

```
interface ButtonPageChange extends ButtonProps {}

function ButtonPageChange(props: ButtonPageChangeProps) { 
  const { className, ...buttonProps } = props; // Object destructuring to pass all props down to `Button`
  return (
    <Button 
      {...buttonProps}  // spread to pass properties to button
      className={'btn-loading ' + className ?? ''} // Null coaleshing operator
      data-senna-off="true"
    />
  );
}
```